# Changing the Date Format on an SQL Server backup

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL script that I'm trying to create that will backup an SQL Server database and add a date/time stamp into the backup name.

When I run my script it adds the date in the wrong format and I'm not sure how to rectify it. The date it adds says "**01 Sept 2023 09:00:00**" when I want to add it like "**01-09-2023-09:00:00**"

```
DECLARE @filename varchar(500)
DECLARE @db1 varchar(500)
DECLARE @url varchar(500)
DECLARE @date nvarchar(256)

SET @date = REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(256),GetDate(), 113),':','-');

SELECT @url = 'https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/sql-migration-data/db1/'
SELECT @date
SELECT @db1 = 'db1_diff_'

SET @filename = @url + @db1 + @date + '.bak'

BACKUP DATABASE [db1] TO  URL = @filename WITH  DIFFERENTIAL , NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'db1-Differential Database Backup', NOSKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Comment: You can achieve what you want like this SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(256),GetDate(), 105) +'-' + CONVERT(nvarchar(256),GetDate(), 108) but I am pretty positive that you can't backup a database with special characters like ':'

Comment: Check the list of [Date and time styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles) and replace 113 in `CONVERT(nvarchar(256),GetDate(), 113)` with the one you want. I'd strongly advise using 112 or 120 though, because `01-09-2023` is both ambiguous (January 9?) and can't be sorted in date order

Comment: Since you're using cloud storage `01-09-2023` is a *very* bad format. Blob storage in all clouds has no folders. Buckets are flat containers and folders are emulated through prefix searches. That means you can easily find all files in 2023 or September 2023 if you use `2023-09-01` and search for all matches of `2023-09`, or use `-` as the "directory" separator. With `01-09-2023` though you'll have to search all files to find matches. Not only is this slow, but you'll pay for it in storage transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create an SQL Server backup script that adds a date and time stamp to the backup file name in the format "dd-mm-yyyy-hh:mi:ss". Your current script is producing a different date format. To achieve your desired format, you can use the CONVERT function with style 120 to format the date correctly, and then replace spaces and colons with hyphens in the resulting string.

```
SET @date = REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(256), GetDate(), 120), ' ', '-'), ':', '-');
```